# Simplification of a specific limit using l'Hospital's rule

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

I have a doubt about a solution I found on my analysis textbook:
$$f'(n)=\lim_{x\to n}\frac{f(x)-f(n)}{x-n} =\lim_{x\to n} \frac{f'(x)}{1}$$
I don't get why $f(n)$ on the numerator has disappeared: shouldn't it become $f'(n)$ (instead of disappearing), as L'Hospital has been applied? Or is there any trick that turned it to zero?

Comment: This kind of solution is totally non-rigorous and should be avoided. However the term $f(n)$ vanishes because it is a constant when differentiating with respect to $x$. It is unfortunate that even "analysis" textbooks are also using such non-rigorous techniques. I thought such lack of rigor prevailed in calculus textbooks only.

Comment: Even I, a rather strong supporter of l'Hospital rule and its use, see this as a rather non-serious and even fundamentally incorrect use of l'H: you use *in the definition* of derivative a method that uses derivatives? I don't think so.

Comment: May I know which analysis textbook you are studying from? I seriously think it is time to change textbook.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ParamanandSingh I will change textbook.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Joanpemo , I had the same feeling when I saw a method that uses derivatives in the definition of derivative ... I will change textbook.

Comment: He seem  used L'Hospital rule